# What do I need to know when adding more RAM on windows?

Tags: windows-7, memory

I'm using a PC in windows 7 and I want to add additional RAM into this machine. For some special reason, I cannot remove any existing RAM. My questions are :

- What is the current type of my RAMs ?
- Should I care about the compatibility of the existing one and the new one ?
- Or any other point I should be aware.

Here's my existing RAMs information using `wmic` in cmd.

```
C:\Windows\system32>wmic MemoryChip get BankLabel, Capacity, MemoryType, TypeDet
ail, Speed
BankLabel  Capacity    MemoryType  Speed  TypeDetail
BANK 1     2147483648  0           1067   128
BANK 3     2147483648  0           1067   128
```

Comment: Which motherboard do you have. Look up its manual. If you do not have that, use wmic and hope that the vender filled in the values where he was supposed to (rather than 'boardname here' 'version here' etc etc). Alternatively CPU-Z and check which memory you have now so you know what you need to buy,

Comment: Do you mean baseboard ? `wmic baseboard get Manufacturer` shows that its manufacturer is _Dell Inc._. And the manufacturer of memory chip is _830B_.

Comment: Not just the manufacturer, the actual model. Optionally via the servicetag and the Dell website. If it used DDR2-800 then you need some more DDR2-800. Ect etc

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'm doing something else for the moment. I'll update the post if I need additional information

Comment: You should also consider if you have a 32 vs 64 bit OS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run [CPU-Z](http://www.cpuid.com/softwares/cpu-z.html) to see which RAM you already have and purchase RAM with the same speed/timings to avod compatibility issues when using RAM modules with different timings.

If you use the Windows 7 Home Premium, make sure you don't exceed 16GB RAM, because the Home Premium Edition has a limitation to only support 16GB RAM.

If you still use a 32Bit Windows 7, you should install the 64Bit Windows 7 to use more than 4GB RAM.